# NSS DTLS sample application codes

Tags: nss, dtls

Is there sample standalone "application" codes of utilizing NSS DTLS/SRTP features somewhere available?

There are sample application codes of cmd & tests that utilize SSL3/TLS features that come with NSS Mozilla releases, but none for DTLS features - though there is DTLS support in nss/lib/ssl/ codes, but those are to SSL3/DTLS internal working.

I have tried googling for days but to no avail. I've been trying for a couple of weeks to write codes to access those internal codes, which requires quite a lot hacking to create internal hooks in ssl/ directory, which I think is not the right approach and not going well. But I simply can't find a reasonable API, in dtlscon.c, ssl3con.c and etc.,  for application to use or a sample app to follow.

Could someone provide some hints or a sample standalone client/server application codes that actually utilize the NSS DTLS/SRTP features?

I'm doing the coding in C under NSS cmd/tests or JAVA under nss/jss/org/Mozilla/jss.

Thanks,

Comment: You may want to subscribe to the mailing list instead of asking here.